# AnimatorFactory events?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, adobe

I made a jump move with [AnimatorFactory](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/motion/AnimatorFactory.html#includeExamplesSummary) and wondering if it fires any event when the motion starts or ends like [tween](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html#event%3amotionStart) class?

for example when I use "ani.addTarget(this, 3);" it loops the motion 3 times is there any way to run another function each time it starts moving?
^_^

Comment: You should be able to get the duration of a tween and then add a Timer instance to trigger the call you need each time.

Comment: that was the last thing I wanted to do but I guess there is no easy way to this. thanks George